# DataGridView EditingControlShowing doesn't fire

Tags: c#, datagridview

After a long time of search on the web for my problem, i ask the question...

I have a DataGridView whith DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in the 2 first columns.
When I change **manually** the value of the 1st column of the last row, I add a new blank row after this last row if needed.

When I change **manually** the value of the second column, I change the type of the next columns (Text or Combo) and fill the DataGridViewComboBoxCell.

These 2 points work perfectly with the EditingControlShowing event whitch fires other events. I use this event whitch is the only one returns a ComboBox as e.Control.

My problem is when I want to **programmatically** fill the values of col 1 & col 2, the EditingControlShowing event doesn't fire as it should.

I've tried with BeginEdit property, with EditMode=EditProgrammatically property, with no more success.

Here is a part of my code (this not the project but a part of a sample, and I can send more if necessary) :

```
    private void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string[]> sFilters = new List<string[]>();
        string[] filter1 = { "col3", "NOT IN" };
        string[] filter2 = { "col5", "BETWEEN" };
        sFilters.Add(filter1);
        sFilters.Add(filter2);

        iRow = -1;

        foreach (var sVar in sFilters)
        {
            iRow++;
            try
            {
                iCol = 0;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCol];
                dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = sVar[0];
                //dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("btnFill_Click - iCol=0 - iRow=" + iRow.ToString() + " :\n\n" + Ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                iCol = 1;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCol];
                //dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = sVar[1];
                //dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("btnFill_Click - iCol=1 - iRow=" + iRow.ToString() + " :\n\n" + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        iCol = ((DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        iRow = ((DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (iCol == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // Déclenchement d'un évènement quand 'cboVar' change
                ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
                if (combo != null)
                {
                    // first remove event handler to keep from attaching multiple
                    combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(dataGridView1_cboVar_SelectedIndexChanged);
                    // now attach the event handler
                    combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_cboVar_SelectedIndexChanged);
                }
                ((DataGridView)sender).ClearSelection();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("EditingControlShowing() - Col0 :\n\n" + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else if (iCol == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
                if (combo != null)
                {
                    // first remove event handler to keep from attaching multiple
                    combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(dataGridView1_cboOpe_SelectedIndexChanged);
                    // now attach the event handler
                    combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_cboOpe_SelectedIndexChanged);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("EditingControlShowing() - Col1 :\n\n" + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_cboVar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            comboVar = sender as ComboBox;
            if (iCol == 0)
            {
                if (comboVar.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    if (iRow == dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                }
                comboVar.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(dataGridView1_cboVar_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dataGridView1_cboVar_SelectedIndexChanged() :\n\n" + Ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I hope that I am clear enougth...

Thanks a lot for the help, and sorry for my poor English...

Herve

Comment: `dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);` set this to true and try `dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);`

Comment: Thanks for response. I've tried dataGridView.BeginEdit(true) or (false) with the same result. I's like when CurrentCell is on column 0, the event is not fired (?).

Comment: Where should i put the DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true) ? I've found that the EditingControlShowing event is fired just when BeginEdit is set to true, but not after the cell has changed value. So now how to fire EditingControlShowing after changing value in the DataGridViewComboBoxCell ?

Comment: I had a similiar problem and the issue was that the gridview editingcontrolshowing event was not binded with a gridview,there was an incorrect reference pointing to event.